# Angular material date range picker fails with [opened]="true" set initially

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

We just upgraded our app from Angular (including Angular material) 14 to 15.2.9. The migration scripts completed without errors and the app compiles and is running.
We have discovered an issue with the `mat-date-range-picker`, when `[opened]="true"` is set initially. So the date range picker should be open, when the user enters the page.

Our code is:

```js
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="picker.open()">
    <span>{{ apiFilter.from && apiFilter.to
      ? (apiFilter.from.toFormat('d. MMM yyyy')) + ' til ' + (apiFilter.to.toFormat('d. MMM yyyy'))
      : 'Vælg periode'
      }}
    </span>

    <mat-date-range-input class="date-filter-input" [rangePicker]="picker">
      <input (dateChange)="onUpdateDateRange($event.value, 'from')" [value]="apiFilter.from" matStartDate />
      <input (dateChange)="onUpdateDateRange($event.value, 'to')" [value]="apiFilter.to" matEndDate />
    </mat-date-range-input>

    <mat-date-range-picker #picker [opened]="true"></mat-date-range-picker>
  </button>
```

The button show the selected range and toggle the `picker.open()`. The `mat-date-range-input` is hidden for user by the class `date-filter-input`.
Running this will fail with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_getAccessibleName')
    at MatDateRangeInput._getStartDateAccessibleName (datepicker.mjs:4324:33)
    at MatDateRangePicker._forwardContentValues (datepicker.mjs:4434:54)
    at MatDateRangePicker._openOverlay (datepicker.mjs:2843:14)
    at MatDateRangePicker.open (datepicker.mjs:2743:14)
    at set opened [as opened] (datepicker.mjs:2600:45)
    at Object.ngOnChangesSetInput [as setInput] (core.mjs:1533:26)
    at setInputsForProperty (core.mjs:11643:17)
    at elementPropertyInternal (core.mjs:10782:9)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.mjs:13521:9)
```

Everything is working fine without errors, if we change the initial value `[opened]="false"`!

We are not sure what is wrong here and maybe we missed something in the upgrade to Angular 15?

Any suggestions will be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that, starting as opened, `MatDateRangePicker` tries to access `_getAccessibleName` from `matStartDate` and `matEndDate` before the projected elements they're bound to have been initialized.

To check if this is actually the issue, you could try to bound its `opened` property to a variable initialized as false and turned to true only inside `ngAfterContentInit()`

Comment: Thanks, the solution with `ngAfterContentInit()` result in the same error. But i can confirm that your conclusion may be correct, I changed to `[opened]="(hasValidApiFilter$ | async) === false"` where `hasValidApiFilter$` is an observable.  This observable has `pipe(delay(50))` when it is set, and this solves the problem for now. Should this be reported as a bug in the Angular Material repo?

Comment: A minimal Stackblitz reproduction of the issue would be preferable, because the basic docs' example modified to show the picker already open doesn't suffer the same problem.
So maybe it's better to first check what exact condition triggers that.